# Finding Imaginary part of a complex function with 2 arguments

Tags: functions, complex

How to make mathematica gives the imaginary part of a certain complex function in the form of trigonometric functions such as sin(s-t) and cos(s-t)?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
et[s_] := Cos[s] + I Sin[s];
etp[s_] := I et[s];
A[s_] := (et[s])^3;
NM[s_, t_] := Im[A[s]/A[t] etp[t]/(et[t] - et[s])];
```

From the coding, I only manage to get answer

```
Re[(Cos[s] + I Sin[s])^3/((Cos[t] + I Sin[t])^2 
(-Cos[s] + Cos[t] - I Sin[s] + I Sin[t]))]
```

which is not real expression because still have `I`. I don't understand why the `Im[]` doesn't work. Later on I have more complicated function

```
et[s_]:=(3+2 Cos[2s])(Cos[s] + I Sin[s])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `ComplexExpand`

```
Clear["Global`*"];
et[s_] := Cos[s] + I Sin[s];
etp[s_] := I et[s];
A[s_] := (et[s])^3;
NM[s_, t_] := Im[A[s]/A[t] etp[t]/(et[t] - et[s])];
```

Let's call your expression `e` then

```
e = Re[(Cos[s] + 
      I Sin[s])^3/((Cos[t] + I Sin[t])^2 (-Cos[s] + Cos[t] - 
       I Sin[s] + I Sin[t]))]
```

> Re[(Cos[s] + 
>      I Sin[s])^3/((Cos[t] + I Sin[t])^2 (-Cos[s] + Cos[t] - I Sin[s] + 
>       I Sin[t]))]

This has only wrapped your expression in `Re` For further work you need to identify which terms are real and which are imaginary.  `ComplexExpand` does this with the default assumption that unidentified symbols are real.

```
ComplexExpand[e] // Simplify
```

> -(1/2) - Cos[s - t] - Cos[2 (s - t)]

`Simplify` is not necessary but without it you get a very long expression. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
et[s_] = Cos[s] + I Sin[s];
etp[s_] = I et[s];
A[s_] = (et[s])^3;

NM[s_, t_] = 
 Im[A[s]/A[t] etp[t]/(et[t] - et[s])] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

(* -Cos[2*s - 2*t] - Cos[s - t] - 1/2 *)
```